# How to read CPU usage, RAM usage and Disk usage using filebeat?

Tags: configuration, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat, kibana-6

I am using filebeat, ELK stack. I want to get CPU, RAM, and Disk usage information using filebeat and send it to logstash to elasticsearch to kibana.

Version of ELK stack is:-

```
filebeat 6.5.4
ELK 5.6.4
```

Any body have any idea about the solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this. Filebeat is not able to collect system statistics information it's only for collect system logs and custom logs.

```
Metricbeat is actually used to collect the system statistics information.
Some of them like:-
1. CPU Statistics
2. Memory Statistics
3. And Other Processes, etc
```